# Fastclick not working when clicking edge of element (iOS)

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone-web-app

I'm using [Fastclick 0.6.2](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) from FTLabs, and I'd love for it to work, to remove the 300 ms delay on iOS, but in my application, it detects clicks when I click on the edge of a href block, and nothing happens.

Here's a simple demo page, that has a random number generator with JS, and two page links:
http://nicmar.nu/fastclick/fastclick2b.htm (Open this in your iOS browser)

1. If I click the upper or lower edge of the first green field, the gray webkit-tap-highlight-color shows, but it doesn't run the code test() which is on the href.
2. The same happens on the second green field, which has a link to the page itself.
3. The third green field, is a link to another page. When I click the upper or lower edge here, the address bar shows, which gives the user an indication that something is happening, but it isn't.

The issue is happening on iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 in iOS 6.1, and also on iPad with iOS 6.0. Without fastclick, it works as expected, however with the 300 ms delay.

**Here's a video that shows what's going on:**
http://youtu.be/34kavjxc9xg

PS. I would use jsfiddle, but couldn't get it to display correctly on my iOS with the meta/viewport scale working, due to jsfiddle showing a "fake fullscreen" with an iframe. If anyone can tell me how to get around that, I can input it there.

PS2: I posted this as an issue on the [Fastclick github page](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/86) but didn't get a response there.

[image: Fastclick error]
<sub>(source: [nicmar.nu](http://www.nicmar.nu/fastclick/fastclick-error-2.png))</sub>

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior - it's common enough that it would cause me to not use the script. Would love to hear if anyone else has encountered this and what they did about it.

Comment: We're going to put a developer to analyze what's going on and if it's fixable, but if you have any suggestion for another script that is fast and don't have this issue, please share. Thanks!